# Fullpage.js Cards Extension - Only apply to first slide

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js with the cards extension. Is there any way to apply the card effect to the first slide only and then the regular fullpage.js to the others?

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    cards: true,
    cardsOptions: {
        perspective: 100,
        fadeContent: true,
        fadeBackground: true
    },

    onLeave: function(origin){
        if( origin.index > 0 ){
            // cards: false; <- Does not work...
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read about the available methods for the [Cards extension on the wiki page](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/Extension-Cards) linked from the [the fullpage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)

You can use the following method in the afterLoad callback when detecting a section that is not the 1st:

```
fullpage_api.cards.destroy();
```

Then you can initialise it again with:

```
fullpage_api.cards.init();
```

You can see this applied on the [Cards 3d demo page](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/cards.html) when clicking on the ON and OFF buttons on the bottom left.